# Dynamically changing background color of specific text without changing other attributes

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've written a chrome extension to find text on a page based on a regex query. When text is matched, I wrap the matched text in a `<span>` tag that has the class `highlight` where `highlight` only changes the background color to yellow.

The issue is that sometimes there are already styles applied to `<span>` tags in a webpage. For example, the webpage might have this defined:

```
span {
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

So when I insert my `<span>` tag in another `<span>` tag, the font-size is actually 400%.

Is there an easy way for my code to just change certain properties of the text, like the background color, without applying the webpage's styles twice?

EDIT:

No one really seems to understand what I'm getting at so I'll try to be more clear.

I'm writing a chrome extension. That means the code will run on someone else's webpage. I have no control over their styles. I don't know whether they'll be using percentages for font sizes or fixed values. I don't know which styles they will change.

I don't want to change their styles at all, except for one property. If I reset everything to the default values, that would be changing their styles. If I do nothing, than their styles will be applied twice, like margin, padding, font-size, etc.

Comment: i would probably use a html tag that doesn't get a lot of global styling like `<ins>`

Comment: @jayharris That actually might be my answer. No one else seems to even understand my question.

Comment: Good idea, except that `<ins>` is for [text actually added to the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ins). The correct tag is the `<mark>` element, which is [specifically for highlighted text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark).

Comment: btw if you another tag beware of browser defaults, `<ins>` on chrome is `text-decoration: underline` for instance. so you might want to overwrite that to normal

Comment: @brentonstrine thanks for contributing to my answer, since you couldn't get it the first time. anyways notice how i suggested `<ins>` as an example of a tag a developer might not style globally.

Comment: @jayharris It's never a good idea to *intentionally* misuse an HTML tag out of laziness. The correct tag is `<mark>` and that is what he should use. If he still is worried about developers styling that tag globally (as he should be) then he can use a CSS Reset as I suggested in my answer. It's not that much harder and it doesn't break the semantics of the web.

Comment: @brentonstrine yeah clearly. good catch, but you should have put that as your first answer if you already knew that.

Comment: @jayharris, In fact, I hadn't thought of it. Your comment made me remember the correct semantic tag so I edited my answer to improve it. The goal here is to provide good, complete answer for posterity. Your contribution was helpful, which I acknowledged. I understand that you're trying to build up points, but bickering and accusing people of stealing your ideas isn't going to get you far. Your original comment was great, and deserves an upvote.

Comment: no need to continue this conversation, @brentonstrine your right, and i gave you credit in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from my comments and @brentonstrine change your tags to:

`<mark>`

Answer (score 0):

Give your selected span a specific namespaced classname like

```
<span class="gs-text-selected">
```

or whatever, then write CSS that targets that. You might have to add !important to your styles  if you get cascade issues, but be careful with !important.

Comment: This won't solve the issue of applying styles twice, like in my `font-size: 200%` example.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want a CSS Reset that applies only to `span.highlight`. Here's one I threw together based on Eric Meyer's popular [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/):

```
span.highlight {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Not sure if that covers everything, but it might get most of it. The problem you're going to run into here though is specificity: if there is any CSS that has more specificity, (e.g. it uses an `id` or it uses more `class`es than you) then it will be overwritten. Therefore, the best way to do it would be to actually insert the CSS inline directly into each `<span>` you create:

```
<span class="highlight" style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;display:inline;line-height:1;">found word</span>
```

(BTW, you should use `<mark>`, which [semantically denotes highlighted text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark), instead of `<span>`. Furthermore, choosing a class name more unique than `highlight` will help you avoid, to avoid conflicts.)

Comment: If the webpage has applied the style `margin: 10px` to span, than I want to apply 10px as the margin. In my case, 20px was being applied. With your solution 0px will be applied. Correct?

Comment: I believe so. You'll get whatever margin you specify. If you want to apply `10px` margin, then set that value to `10px` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the text size instead of using a percentage.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonocairns/3EhZx/1/

```
span {
    font-size:2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add tag like "`<mark></mark>`" around it and if you like assign a class to it, but you don't need any additional class it will automatically highlight it with yellow background.

in case you love something fancy

```
mark.heightlight{
  background-color:yellow;
  font-weight:bold;  
}
```